# M.2 SSDs detected after boot, but not after windows restart

Tags: windows, ssd

I have a custom built computer with an ASROCK Z790 Pro RS/D4 mainboard and three M.2 SSDs:
One 1 tb Kingston and two 2 tb Mushkin Tempest.

When I boot my computer everything works fine. However, when I restart Windows 11 loading Windows takes a long time (minutes instead of seconds) and upon login the two Mushkin SSDs don't show up. They do show up in the bios, though.

I can't think of a reason why that would be. The bios is up to date.

Following @harrymc's advice, I checked the event viewer and found the following two error messages:

```
source: stornvme
The driver detected a controller error on \Device\RaidPort2.
The driver detected a controller error on \Device\RaidPort3.
```

I then checked the `device manager` and found that two `standard nvm express controllers` show little yellow triangles. I'm assuming the drivers crashed?  The drivers should be up to date.

Any idea how I could resolve this issue?

Comment: If you're using Windows, check the Event Viewer for pertinent messages.

Comment: When you restart Windows, it slows down (a handful of seconds on top of the normal seconds for loading) to permit easy access to BIOS.  Might you have done something in the machine build or OS build to exacerbate this?

Comment: @harrymc thanks, I edited my question

Comment: @John not that I'm aware of

Comment: The yellow triangles mean that the driver is non-functional. Please add to your post the specifications of these devices and their driver.

Comment: Have you tried a different NVMe driver, for example a generic Phison one? (I realise the Mushkin drives use an InnoGrit IG5216 rather than a Phison chip.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Drivers shouldn’t be required with Windows 11 at least with a single NVMe drive, but I have doubts, we’re dealing with a single drive rather a RAID configuration and in that case a driver lost certainly is required

Comment: @Ramhound the HDDs are not in Raid. I don't know why it says `raid` in the error messages. `Device\RaidPort1\` is where the system HDD is connected (which never makes any problems).

Comment: @Ramhound If the generic Windows driver is reporting an error, then maybe a different driver will work. It seemed to help [user Southern-Ad-4508 on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/framework/comments/yq6f6w/comment/j1nbkmh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Comment: At one point they mentioned the Intel RST driver, which of course, is only required if you have Intel RST enabled within UEFI and is essentially a RAID driver.